# Is the [asp-placeholder] tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Came across [asp-placeholder](/questions/tagged/asp-placeholder) when running through some new questions. On the question I found it, it was completely inappropriate and I think the person was just picking tags until he'd used all 5... separate issue.

Right now there are only 16 questions currently tagged [asp-placeholder](/questions/tagged/asp-placeholder), there is no tag-wiki, and I'm at a bit of a loss as to what purpose this tag serves. Not being a .net guy, is there some component or something I'm missing? Or is this a tag that needs to be addressed?

At the very least it seems a tag-wiki is in order with a definition and usage guidelines... I use those a **lot** when trying to figure out if the tag usage is appropriate.

Comment: I might have named it "asp.net-placeholder", but yes; there is such a component.

Comment: `asp:placeholder`'s are a valid control, yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

Comment: @AndrewBarber then it likely needs to be re-named (as well as a tag-wiki added) as I seem to recall most asp.net components like that are prefixed with `asp.net-` - though I'd have to double-check to be sure.

Comment: the placeholder control predates .NET.  It applies to both classic ASP and .NET.  That said, it also serves the same purpose in both contexts, so I don't see any real need to disambiguate between them.

Comment: @Servy Hmm... I just renamed the tags; they all seemed to be about the ASP.NET control. While they serve the same purpose, I guess my thought was their use is quite different.

Comment: i vote for renaming to asp.net-placeholder , asp-placeholder would be confusing at long term

Comment: @Servy can you point me to a reference for the asp-classic version? I'd like to propose an appropriate tag-wiki but everything I've found via search references the .net control.

Comment: @AnonJr It's literally the exact same class.  There isn't a different version of it for .NET, which is why I don't see a need to disambiguate at all.  That same control can be used from a classic or .NET application, but the control itself is literally the exact same class.  Just look at the examples of the older versions of the class in the language documentation.

Comment: @Servy Oh, really? I had no idea of that at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited those questions and added a new [asp.net-placeholder](/questions/tagged/asp.net-placeholder) to them. There is a classic ASP placeholder control, but my thinking was that the questions were all about the ASP.NET control, and their usage is different.